# Silverlight combobox selected value hidden

Tags: silverlight

Given two simple comboboxes I am able to drop down and select items but the second ddl refuses to show its value while not dropped down!  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  At this point there are no bound events or data its just static as seen here.

```
<ComboBox Height="23" Name="ddlRCC" Width="120" Margin="3,3,474,134">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="RaC1" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="RaC2" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="RaC3" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="RaC4" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="RaC5" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="RaC6" />
</ComboBox>
<ComboBox Height="23" Margin="130,5,314,135" Name="ddlNOSC" Width="156" Padding="140,3,25,2">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="NiSC1" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="NiSC2" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="NiSC3" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="NiSC4" />
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: May that padding value be causing any strange behavior?

Comment: This cant be, I bet you have a line of code where you set your selectedindex somewhere. I've copied the code to my project and it showed no standard selected index. this is because how the comboboxes work when you set the itemssource to some content. You have to manually set the selectedindex to have anything selected as standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for all of your help.

Solved:
I noticed other things not working as they should. And then remembered that I had not rebooted since the last round of updates.  After a reboot the code worked as expected.  I didnt have the time or inclination to try to figure out exactly what the issue was.  But thanks again for the support.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 <ComboBoxItem Content="RaC1" IsSelected="True" />
```

and similar for the other dropdown.

Comment: I tried this as well.  It 'was' selected. You could see it in the dropped down portion but not when it was 'un-dropped down' It was most odd.  As I added here the reboot was the solution. There were MS updates and i installed Expression after the updates without restarting. And I believe windows was demanding its pound of reboot. :)